# Is it possible to combine two IQueryable of different types?

Tags: entity-framework, rest, linq

I have a database with two tables, brands and models.

I have a situation where I want to be able to query `Model` based on its respective `Brand` name.

`Brand` has many `Model`
`Model` has one `Brand`

```
public class Brand
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public List<Model> Models { get; set; } = new List<Model>();
}

public class Model
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int BrandId { get; set; }
    public Brand Brand { get; set; }
}
```

Each entity also has a filter where I can filter on `Ids` and `Names`

```
public class BrandFilter
{
    public List<int> Ids { get; set; }
    public List<string> Names { get; set; }
}

public class ModelFilter
{
    public List<int> Ids { get; set; }
    public List<string> Names { get; set; }
    public BrandFilter BrandFilter { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see the `ModelFilter` holds a `BrandFilter`, this is because I want to be able to search for models that belongs to specific brand names.

What I can do to accomplish this with Linq is the following

```
IQueryable<Model> query = _context.Models.AsQueryable();

query = query.Where(model => modelFilter.Ids.Contains(model.Id));

query = query.Where(model => modelfilter.BrandFilter.Names.Contains(model.Brand.Name));
```

The actual model filter (as JSON) sent to the `/models` endpoint would look like this

```
(This a a modelFilter)

{
    "ids": [
        32,
        87,
        135
    ],
    "brandFilter": {
        "names": [
            "BMW",
            "Mercedes-Benz"
        ]
    }
}
```

The response would give me all models that has an id of 32 `OR` 87 `OR` 135 `AND WHERE` brand name is "BMW" `OR` "Mercedes-Benz"

Now to the problem ...

The example above works great with trivial cases where I only have two entities. But keep in mind that there's also and endpoint for `/brands`.
This endpoint would have the exact same query logic regarding the brand names, it would look something like this

```
IQueryable<Brand> query = _context.Brands.AsQueryable();

query = query.Where(brand => brandfilter.Names.Contains(brand.Name));
```

The problem is that I have to write redundant code for the query logic on both endpoints `/models` and `/brands`

What I have tried so far is creating a service for each entity which handles the query logic, think of something like this.

The service below returns an `IQueryable` of its type, and it is this `IQueryable` I want to be able to "concat" to the `IQueryable<Model>`

```
SearchBrandService

public IQueryable<Brand> Query(BrandFilter filter)
{
    IQueryable<Brand> query = _context.Brands.AsQueryable();

    if (filter.Ids != null)
    {
        var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Brand>();

        foreach (var id in filter.Ids)
        {
            predicate = predicate.Or(brand => brand.Id == id);
        }

        query = query.Where(predicate);
    }

    if (filter.Names != null)
    {
        var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Brand>();

        foreach (var name in filter.Names)
        {
            predicate = predicate.Or(brand => brand.Name.ToLower().Contains(name.ToLower()));
        }

         query = query.Where(predicate);
    }

    return query;
}
```

I would then like to use the above method in the service `SearchModelService` below

```
public IQueryable<Model> Query(ModelFilter filter)
{
    IQueryable<Model> query = _context.Models.AsQueryable();

    ... Here are the filter for the Models Ids and Names (removed for abbreviation) ...

    if (filter.BrandFilter != null)
    {
        IQueryable<Brand> subQuery = _searchBrandService.Query(filter.BrandFilter);
        query = query.Concat(subQuery); // This gives 'IQueryable<Model>' does not contain a definition for 'Concat'
    }

    return query;
}
```

When I try to concat `IQueryable<Model>` with `IQueryable<Brand>` it complains, I believe this is because they are different types.

I hope you understand the problem at this point.

Any hints or solutions as to how I can combine two IQueryable of different types?

Comment: I'd consider posting this under CodeReview rather than StackOverflow... From a personal experience / opinion point, avoiding duplicating what amounts to a few lines of easy to read & understand Linq logic and trying to abstract out and then re-integrate a predicate builder isn't worth losing sleep over.  ;)

Comment: Never heard about CodeReview, will check it out. I agree that over-abstraction just adds complexity but in this case I think it would make sense. In this trivial case with just two entities it's easy to maintain the query logic, for sure. But what happens when more properties are added to e.g. Brand and there are more relationships to each entity? The downside would be that as soon something changes in an entity I have to update this query logic on different places through out the codebase. Thanks for your opinion anyway!